# Upgrade Angular application from 2.4.0 rc.1 to angular 4 or Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

Hello I am looking for updating my Angular application which is currently residing on Angular ng-version 2.4.0 rc.1 to new angular 4 /5. My question is which version should i migrate to angular version 4 or 5? which is stable version and which will be fully supported. I am looking for change to make my application run faster and more robust and mainly improve it performance wise. I am using highcharts and kendo grid libraries in my application. I want suggestion to move to which version and which guide to follow up so I don't land up in chaos and fixing bugs. Also my application says - Your global Angular CLI version (1.4.9) is greater than your local
version (1.0.0-rc.0). The local Angular CLI version is used. so do i have to upgrade cli version too? Below is my package.json file -

```
  {
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "0.20.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "0.16.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "0.32.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "0.16.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "0.21.4",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "0.3.6",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "0.13.8",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.19.6",
    "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "1.33.4",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "0.5.5",
    "angular2-tooltip": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "cytoscape-qtip": "^2.7.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "js-polyfills": "^0.1.34",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng-lightning": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.2",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "primeng": "^2.0.0",
    "qtip": "0.0.4",
    "qtip2": "^3.0.3",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.64",
    "@types/node": "6.0.68",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should upgrade to the latest stable version of the CLI (see [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases)), and the latest stable version of angular (see [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)). A stable version is one which not an alpha, beta or RC version. And you should do that on a very regular basis, rather than doing it every two years. That would avoid having to read a whole lot of release notes to find the breaking changes, and would allow you to learn about new stuff as it appears.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff, which is helpful to know what to changes in files generated by the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Angular update tool](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) for help on possible issues.

When you use angular cli from your command line, it uses the global version. When it's used from inside your projects script, it uses the local version. Keep it up to date both globally and locally as much as you can. Update the CLI before creating a new shell for your new application, and then copy your package.json, app folder and other dependencies to your new shell.

Good luck :)